# Problems with Sessions and Iframes

Tags: php, session, iframe

Good afternoon!

I have a website that allows you to log in and use a 3rd party app via Iframe. Once they are finished with their application however, it redirects to our site inside the iframe, only when the user is redirected to our site from the Iframe, they are not logged in inside of the iframe. What would be the best way to transfer the session from the host, to the Iframe?

So far I have inside the iframe www.test.com?sid=34324vcsd3 which I believe works great. however whenever they direct, they redirect me to www.mysite.com/page that is not currently logged in through the Iframe. Even though Im logged in through the host page, I am not logged in through the Iframe.

I think I have two options 
 1. Find a way to share the session with the Iframe

or

2 find a way to use HTTP_Referer to pull the sessionID from the iframe page pre transfer.

for example I am sent from test.com?sid=3d3er3e3 to www.test.com/page where test.com/page calls HTTP_referer. I can successfully get the test.com?sid=3d3er3e3, but I'm not sure how to extract the SID

What would you guys recommend? Is it possible to share the session with the IFrame? or is there a way to pull the sessionID from the http_referer string?

Or recommend a better solution if you know it - I am pretty new to this, but have spent over a day trying to figure this out. any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I recommend never using iframes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - but getting rid of the Iframe is not an option. it is a very simple application, but it would cost us too much to have the third party application change how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're trying to pass session information through a GET variable instead of using browser cookies. Read the PHP manual on Sessions here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

The quick, simple explanation of how sessions work is that you could do this on one page:

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "foobar";
?>
```

... and then this on another page:

```
<?
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

...and the second page would display "foobar", regardless of where the user came from (as long as they had visited the first page at least once already).

Comment: Thanks for the assitance, but so far the issue is that despite being logged in on the "Host" page (the page containing the Iframe) the session variables to do transfer to the website through the Iframe. 

for example - if I log in to my site, go to the myaccount page of my website, and then try to open the myaccount page through an Iframe, my session inside the Iframe does not exist until I log in again.

Comment: @RobertDickey of course not,  they are domains specific, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Dagon, I am aware of this, that is why I'm trying to find a work around.

Comment: @RobertDickey if there was a work around for site A reading site B cookies, who would be using it?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. When you say, "I have a website that allows you to log in and use a 3rd party app via Iframe," do you mean they log in to YOUR site, or to the third-party site in the iframe? If they log in to your site, there's no reason that a session variable you set during login wouldn't still exist when the iframe returns to your site at the end of the process. If they're logging into the third-party site, you'll have to talk to the third-party company about passing identity information if they don't already do so.

Comment: my fault. They log into MY site, and access the Iframe from a page on my site. That Iframe is just a generic application that they use, and when they are finished with the application. they redirected from their application to our page, while still in the iframe. The problem is - when they are redirected inside that i frame, they do not appear to still be logged in.  For example if I log in to my site, use the Iframe application, once finished the webpage inside the iframe is redirect to our site. When redirected to our site they do not have a active session and are asked to log in.

Comment: They should still be logged in within the iframe then. It should have nothing to do with what pages they viewed in the iframe before coming back to your site. If you create another iframe that just goes directly to the trouble page (the one on your site that visitors get to within the iframe) without visiting the third-party, so you still have the same problem? Try posting the code you use to log them in and the code you use to check whether they're logged in.

Comment: You are right. It is working properly when I open my page in an iframe. let me post my code.